# bash command substitution freezes script (output too long?)--how to cope

Tags: bash, command, output, freeze, substitution

I have a bash script that includes a line like this:

```
matches="`grep --no-filename $searchText $files`"
```

In other words, I am assigning the result of a grep to a variable.

I recently found that that line of code seems to have a vulnerability: if the grep finds too many results, it annoyingly simply freezes execution.

First, if anyone can confirm that excessive output (and exactly what constitutes excessive) is a known danger with command substitution, please provide a solid link for me.  I web searched, and the closest reference that I could find is in [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

"Do not set a variable to the contents of a long text file unless you have a very good reason for doing so."

That hints that there is a danger, but is very inadequate.

Second, is there a known best practice for coping with this?

The behavior that I really want is for excessive output in command substitution
to generate a nice human readable error message followed by an error exit code so that my script will terminate instead of freeze.  (Note: I always run my scripts with "set -e" as one of the initial lines).  Is there any way that I can get this behavior?

Currently, the only solution that I know of is a hack that sorta works just for my immediate case: I can limit the output from grep using its --max-count option.

Comment: "Freezes execution"? Not really. It might run out and memory and fail (which isn't freezing), or it might go into swap (which could slow the system down a *lot*) if you don't have ulimits set to appropriately limit per-process memory allocation, but there isn't a state that's just frozen.

Comment: BTW, reflexively using `set -e` [is not necessarily a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). (Ignore the allegory if it's too much to read, but *do* see how many of the quiz questions below you can get right in deciding whether you understand the behavior of `set -e` well enough to use it safely).

Comment: As another aside, `$files` as an unquoted expansion is a code smell -- indicates that your code almost certainly won't work correctly in the presence of filenames with spaces, for example, and can also make things surprising when names contain glob metacharacters. Best practice is to store lists in an array; for instance: `files=( *.txt )`, and then dereferencing `"${files[@]}"`

Comment: @Charles: "Freezes execution" maybe is not technically accurate, but it sure seemed like it: I have seen that grep inside the command substitution not finish executing for an hour.  In contrast, when I execute the very same grep on its own, it completes in maybe 10 seconds (in my case, where it found ~500,000 matching lines).  By the way, I am using a freshly installed 32 bit cygwin installation on a windows 10 box, so some of the behavior that I am seeing could be an artifact of that.

Comment: @Charles thanks for the link warning about `set -e`.  I did not have time to go thru the exercises at the end, but the description at the top indicates that most of the complication is due to `set -e` NOT getting triggered in situations where you think it should.  This is to cope with so many commands that return non-0 exit codes that are not really severe errors.  In fact, grep is a great example: it returns 1 if no match is found.  If that understanding is true, then you probably should still reflexively call `set -e`, but just beware that it will not catch everything.  That correct?

Comment: There are absolutely failure cases that go the other way around -- consider incrementing an integer with `(( i++ ))` -- if you have `set -e` active it'll end your script.

Comment: And if you're depending on `set -e` to catch errors, then that means you presumably aren't writing manual error handling anymore, which means that situations that disable it contrary to expectation (ie. `somefunc || foobar` preventing `set -e` from having an effect anywhere in `somefunc`) will leave your code in the impacted context without any error handling at all.

Comment: (and re: the hang -- an artifact of cygwin definitely does sound plausible).

Comment: (err, "it'll end your script" if the initial value is 0, to clarify my comment above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't capture data of unknown length into memory *at all*; if you read it as you need it, then `grep` will wait until the content is ready to use.

That is:

```
while IFS= read -r match; do
  echo "Found a match: $match"
  # example: maybe we want to look at whether a match exists on the filesystem
  [[ -e $match ]] && { echo "Got what we needed!" >&2; break; }
done < <(grep --no-filename "$searchText" "${files[@]}")
```

That way, `grep` only writes a line when `read` is ready to consume it (and will block instead of needing to continue to read input if it has more output already produced than can be stored in the relatively small pipe buffer) -- so the names you don't need don't even get generated in the first place, and there's no need to allocate memory or deal with them in any other way.

Comment: Heh. If I'd known you were on cygwin I might have not suggested process substitution (the `<()` syntax) -- it had a longstanding bug that impacted it -- but it turns out upstream [finally got that fixed](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-04/msg00120.html).